# InvalidOperationException Occur when trying to run the insert query of Linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

InvalidOperationException:
Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(PollOptionVote)' because it has no primary key

But Table(PollOptionVote) contains a primary key

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me a couple of times that the DBML file is out of sync with the DB.

First, doublecheck that it really has a primary key.
Afer that, open your dbml file, remove the table, add it again.